# Prevent resizing of rectangles in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, rectangles

I have three rectangles in a report. One wide at the top (as a header), and two tall ones side by side (like two columns, imagine a newspaper). I want the header to be the same width as both rectangles side by side.

When I'm designing or previewing it on Visual Studio it appears fine, but when I view my deployed report on a browser, the two rectangles on the bottom grow, so that the header is no longer flush with the rectangles.

Any way of preventing the rectangles from growing when displayed? Thank you.

Comment: What is in the rectangles?  Just text?

Comment: Hi, I have three tables inside and some graphs. I've figured out that if I remove the tables, the rextangle stops resizing. But I really need the tables in there.

Comment: Can you try making the tables smaller?